# Loading images using an InputStream

Tags: java, jar

In my IDE I'm able to get the path of an image that is in my resource folder and make that path a new file object by doing this:

```
URL imagePath = getClass().getResource("/image.png");
try
{
    //Convert the URLs into URIs and make a file object with that path
    File image = new File(imagePath.toURI());

}
catch (URISyntaxException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I make a jar file of my program I get the error URI is not hierarchical. And I have done some research and found out that I have to create an InputStream using the getResourceAsStream() method. But I do not know how to make that work for an image. I just need to be able to get the path of the image from my resource folder. How would I make this work even if its a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert the `URL` to a `File` reference, this defeats the point of having the embedded resource and embedded resources are simply entries inside a zip file, so they can't be treated as a `File`.

Instead, use something like `ImageIO.read(imagePath)`

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution in this case would be to ask the `ClassLoader` directly for an `InputStream` (using [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)) and pass that to [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-).

Here is a complete example.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ClassLoader clsldr = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        for (final String path : args) {
            try {
                InputStream is = null;
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    is = clsldr.getResourceAsStream(path);
                    if (is != null) {
                        image = ImageIO.read(is);
                        if (image != null) {
                            // Do something with the image.
                            System.out.printf("%s: %d x %d%n",
                                              path,
                                              image.getWidth(),
                                              image.getHeight());
                        } else {
                            System.err.printf("error: %s: %s%n",
                                              path,
                                              "not a valid image file");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.err.printf("error: %s: %s%n",
                                          path,
                                          "no such resource");
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                System.err.printf("error: %s: %s%n", path, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Say I have a picture file `photo.jpg` and then compile above file and create a JAR file like this

```
$ javac *.java
$ jar -cfe example.jar Main *.class photo.jpg
```

then I can run the program like this and get the following output.

```
$ java -jar example NoSuchThing Main.class photo.jpg
error: NoSuchThing: no such resource
error: Main.class: not a valid image file
photo.jpg: 328 x 328
```

Comment: Your answer is a great one if I use an InputStream. But MadProgrammer pointed out that I don't have to use an InputStream, I was getting an error because I was converting a URL into a URI then into a File. So in my case his answer is just simpler.